# Speculate that this is due to the fact

Tags: meaning

I was wondering if there is a better alternative than the phrase "We speculate that this is due to the fact that..."

Because "speculate" sounds like a hypothesis and so I feel it doesn't match well with "fact". Is there a better word to replace fact ?

Comment: How about "We speculate that this is because" ?

Comment: *Speculate* does not relate to the *fact* -- What is speculated is based on a certain fact. No need to confuse. HTH.

Comment: "Due to the fact that" is excess verbiage. Rewite using _because of_, _due to_, or _because_ as a subordinating conjunction. _Speculate_ is, well, too speculative. If something like _surmised_ or _determined_ is too strong, say "The evidence suggests that..."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is seeking style advice rather than focusing on a query about grammar, semantics, punctuation....

Comment: @ColinFine thank you I will be using your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sure want to steer away from these kinds of phrases. As KarlG mentioned, it is verbose. And as  Kris pointed out, you don't have to worry about *speculate* conflicting with *fact*--which appears to be your main concern. They do not conflict because the speculation (theorizing, etc) is based on facts, which is exactly what the sentence is trying to say.

Yet, again, don't torture your readers with sentences of this kind. The word *due*, as Colin Fine suggested, could be replaced with *because* and just that will improve your writing markedly. Though not a priority you may want to replace *speculate*, perhaps with simpler synonyms: **think, deem, posit, understand, opine,** etc. It depends on where in your piece this sentence is going. If this is at the end, you may want to use stronger terms as **theorize or conclude**.

It also depends on the discipline you are writing in. In the hard sciences, terminology tends to follow stricter definitions, and you may want to look for examples. At the other extreme, in the humanities, you have a bit more leeway, and it depends on the trends and subjects.

So, to offer a simple suggestion:

**"We think this is because..."**

You do not need to include "the fact". Rather, just say what the fact is. Often the fewer words the better.

My two cents.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on context and your degree of certainty, you may say:

- We suppose...
- We wonder whether...
- We suspect that...
- We are inclined to believe...
- We were lead to believe...
- We have no doubts that...
- We are sure that...